# How to observe output of rectifier in simulink?

Tags: simulink

As shown in image below, i would like to see the output of the rectifier on the scope but am unable to connect it to the scope because a red dotted line appears in that connection [image]

Answer (score 0):

To convert between the Physical Modelling world and the standard Simulink world, you need to use a [PS-Simulink Converter](https://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/simscape/ref/simulinkpsconverter.html) block.

Also see: [Connecting Simscape Diagrams to Simulink Sources and Scopes](https://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/simscape/ug/connecting-simscape-diagrams-to-simulink-sources-and-scopes.html)